# Finding Vectors with 2 points

Tags: python, vector, pygame, direction

Im helping my friend out with a pygame but we are stuck

so were are trying to get the direction of a projectile but we cant find out how

for example:

[1,1] will go SE

[1,-1] will go NE

[-1,-1] will go NW

and [-1,1] will go SW

we need an equation of some sort that will take the player pos and the mouse pos and find which direction the projectile needs to go

here is where we are plugging in the vectors:

```
def update(self):

    self.rect.x += self.vector[0]
    self.rect.y += self.vector[1]
```

then we are blitting the projectile at the rects coords

Comment: What is the rule supposed to be behind this equation? Does the player fire in the direction of the vector from the player to the mouse cursor? Or from the center of the screen to the mouse cursor? Or something else? Is she restricted to the 8 compass directions, or can she fire at any angle in between?

Comment: the player can fire from in any direction say the player clicks in front of the player the arrow will go straight ahead if the player clicks in back of the character the arrow goes back words so given the mousepos and the player pos we need to find which direction the arrow needs to go

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So, first you want to get the vector distance from the player to the cursor. [Subtracting two points gives you the vector between them](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_addition#Addition_and_subtraction):

```
distance = [mouse.x - player.x, mouse.y - player.y]
```

Now, you want to [normalize that to a unit vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalized_vector). To do that, you just get the norm (by the [Pythagorean theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem)), and divide the vector by the norm:

```
norm = math.sqrt(distance[0] ** 2 + distance[1] ** 2)
direction = [distance[0] / norm, distance[1] / norm]
```

Finally, you want the [velocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity) vector. You get that by [multiplying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector#Scalar_multiplication) the direction (the unit vector) by the speed.

Since you want a bullet fired to the SE to have vector `[1, 1]`, you (presumably) want all bullets to move at the speed of that velocity vector, which is `sqrt(2)` (by the Pythagorean theorem again). So:

```
bullet_vector = [direction[0] * math.sqrt(2), direction[1] * math.sqrt(2)]
```

And that's it.

---

[Here](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import+math%0A%0Aclass+Point%28object%29%3A%0A++++def+__init__%28self,+x,+y%29%3A%0A++++++++self.x,+self.y+%3D+x,+y%0A%0Aplayer+%3D+Point%2810.0,+25.0%29%0Amouse+%3D+Point%2830.0,+70.0%29%0Aspeed+%3D+math.sqrt%282%29%0A%0Adistance+%3D+%5Bmouse.x+-+player.x,+mouse.y+-+player.y%5D%0Anorm+%3D+math.sqrt%28distance%5B0%5D%2a%2a2+%2B+distance%5B1%5D%2a%2a2%29%0Adirection+%3D+%5Bdistance%5B0%5D/norm,+distance%5B1%5D/norm%5D%0Abullet_vector+%3D+%5Bdirection%5B0%5D%2aspeed,+direction%5B1%5D%2aspeed%5D%0A%0Aprint%28bullet_vector%29%0A&mode=display&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&drawParentPointers=false&textReferences=false&showOnlyOutputs=false&py=2&curInstr=14) you can see this code working. (That's an interactive visualizer, so you can step through it piece by piece if there's any part you don't understand.)

I create a player at `[10.0, 25.0]`, and a mouse pointer off a generally (but not exactly) south-easterly direction at `[30.0, 70.0]`, and `bullet_vector` ends up as `[0.5743665268941905, 1.2923246855119288]`, a vector pointing in that same general south-easterly direction with speed `sqrt(2)`.

This shows that it can go southeast (if you want to go *exactly* southeast, change line 8 to `mouse = Point(30.0, 45.0)`), it can go in directions other than the 8 compass points, and it always goes at the same speed.

Comment: this seems to only work in the 8 compass directions but it wont go SE at all?

Comment: Are your `x` and `y` values integers? If so, you will want to convert them to `float`. (You can do that just by doing `** 2.0` instead of `** 2` in the `norm` line.)

Comment: Meanwhile, these are the right formulas. If you need help debugging your code, you need to actually show us your code. (Ideally a small, runnable [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.)

Comment: the code works becuase if i use the slope formula it works but i cant regulate the speed so i cant do that

Comment: @ChristianCareaga: I don't understand the last comment. What do you mean by "regulate the speed", why can't you do it, and what is the other thing you can't do because of it?

Comment: well using slope the further the mouse is from the player the faster the arrow goes but we want to change the direction but keep the same speed your solution does that but only in 8 directions we want 360 degree mobility

Comment: Then you've clearly copied something wrong. Let me edit my answer to show a link to an online visualizer so you can see that my code works.

Comment: i print `bullet_vector` and i get two big long floats but for some reason there being rounded i think!

Comment: @ChristianCareaga: Again, if you do not show us the code you're actually running, nobody can possibly help you. Did you try the link to the online visualizer I gave you? It clearly prints out `[0.5743665268941905, 1.2923246855119288]`, not two big long floats. If your code does something different, you have to show us your code. You can paste it at the same site, or on http://pastebin.com, or you can edit your question or create a new one… but you have to put it somewhere. Nobody can guess what you might have done wrong in code you won't show us.

Comment: i thought i linked to the repo and those are long floats(atleast thats what i meant) but we will figure it out youre formula works though

Comment: @ChristianCareaga: Well, all floats have the same number of digits of precision, so "long" doesn't really mean anything important. The key is the _size_ of the numbers—both smaller than sqrt(2), no more than one of them ridiculously tiny. (Or, more specifically, the sum of their squares should be 2.) And most places you put the mouse will be, say, 13.71231241432 degrees E of SE from the player, so of course the vector's usually not going to have any nice round numbers in it.

Comment: We got it to work we used youres just a little tweaked thanks!here is what we did
https://gist.github.com/C-Dubb/5874883

Comment: @ChristianCareaga: I forgot about `math.hypot`. Nice; it definitely makes things more readable!